# How can I pass a HashMap to gsp page and then back to the controller?

Tags: list, grails, groovy, hashmap, gsp

I have values that I need to pass around in the structure of

```
type1 : value1, value2, value3
type2 : value4, value5, value6
type3 : value7, value8, value8
```

So I made a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()` in my controller and I pass it to my `gsp` file like this:

```
def queryMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()
//fill in data
render(template: "/item/myPage", model: [queryMap: queryMap])
```

Then in my `gsp` page I would like to pass it back to my controller like this:

```
<g:link action="myNewPage" controller="item" params='[queryMap: "${queryMap}"]'>fun</g:link>
```

Then in `myNewPage` controller method I would like to get the map like this:

```
def queryMap = params.queryMap as HashMap
```

But for some reason my map is not getting passed around correctly?  How can I properly pass a map with a list to my gsp file then back to my controller?

If you need nay more information let me know.

Comment: ..because you are missing `[`? `params='[queryMap: "${queryMap}"]'`

Comment: Why give the data by params ? May the user modify it ? You should look for Command object with collection. If not, why can't you regenerate the data ?

Comment: @dmahapatro I did miss that but that wasn't it.

Comment: @Isammoc The user can add things to the list.

Comment: You cannot pass complex objects such as lists in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Use as below without interpolating `queryMap` (without `${}`)

```
<g:link action="myNewPage" 
        controller="item" 
        params="[queryMap: queryMap]">fun</g:link>
```

Moreover, you do not need to infer the type `as HashMap`, by default it is. I would also agree to @Isammoc about coming up with an appropriate data model (by using form etc.) instead of flowing over the model back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to serialize the whole map and then pass it around and deserialize when you need it. You could convert the whole Map into JSON and pass it as a String.